# equivalent routing from action to routing.yml

Tags: php, symfony, routes

```
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return array('name' => $name);
    }

    // ...
}
```

> ```
> /**
>  * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
>  * @Template()
>  */
> ```

how can i move this to file routing.yml ?  i would like create all routing in these file, not in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html
According to this documentation, your rules will look like this:

```
_demo_hello:
    pattern: /hello/{name}
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello
```

However, as far as I know you can't create the @Template() behaviour in your routing file. You'll have to write the code to return a template from your controller. Like this:

```
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
}
```